# How to make a background video For iOS application in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, background

I am making an ios application the i want to know how can i use a video as background?!
Actually the "Vine" application already did it.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: i want to use a video with MPMoviePlayerController in loop mode to play a video as a background.

Comment: What do you mean by as a background? You mean you want the sound to keep playing when you go to the home screen?

Comment: i want a video instead that glasses image    http://axgig.com/images/61023897814126083758.png

Answer (score 2):

you can hide the movieplayercontroller's default controls, and add any other views. it's just like set the video as the background.

Comment: what about looping it ?!

Comment: there is a property named repeatMode, but i am not sure it will be work since i never used it.

Comment: if the repeatMode is not work, there is also a stupid way to solve it. you can listen to the finish event of the playercontroller, and restart the player when receive the event.